# npm workspaces - skip `src` folder when importing source files from symlinked shared package

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, node-modules

I have a typescript monorepo setup that uses npm workspaces and I want to be able to import subpaths down to any individual typescript file of  `@package/shared` in `@package/client` and `@package/server` while skipping the `src` folder. One solution is simply removing the `src` folder and moving every subfolder up the hierarchy but that feels like a hacky solution. I tried using wildcards in the exports (e.g. `"./*": "./src/*"`, `"./": "./src/*.ts"`) but either they're not working or they only work partially (`moduleResolution` is set to `"NodeNext"`)

For example, with the following folder structure of the monorepo

```
.
├── package.json
└── packages/
    ├── shared/
    │   ├── package.json
    │   └── src/
    │       ├── index.ts
    │       ├── types/
    │       │   ├── index.ts
    │       │   ├── foo-type.ts
    │       │   └── bar-type.ts
    │       └── constants/
    │           ├── index.ts
    │           ├── foo-const.ts
    │           └── bar-const.ts
    ├── client/
    │   └── ...
    └── server/
        └── ...
```

I want to be able to import any typescript file in the shared package while skipping `src`

```
import { ... } from "@package/shared"
import { ... } from "@package/shared/types"
import { ... } from "@package/shared/types/foo-type"
import { ... } from "@package/shared/types/bar-type"
import { ... } from "@package/shared"
import { ... } from "@package/shared/constants"
import { ... } from "@package/shared/constants/foo-const"
import { ... } from "@package/shared/constants/bar-const"

// shouldn't work!
import { ... } from "@package/src/shared/..."
```